# Разделяемые ресурсы между процессами в python и мьютексы

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, multiprocessing, uvicorn

Как проблему разделяемых ресурсов решает `uvicorn`?

Запускаю:

```
uvicorn main.py:app --workers=5 --port=8080 --host=0.0.0.0
```

Внутри app есть мьютекс (`threading.Lock()` на часть одного из эндпоинтов). Будет ли этот мьютекс корректно работать, когда я запускаюсь из-под `uvicorn`? Не возникнет ли гонки? Как уберечься от этого? А если заменю `threading` на `multiprocessing` ?

---

## Решаемая задача

Есть сервис, для части одного из эндпоинтов нужен мьютекс на 3 запроса (проверить наличие объектов по фильтру (можно редуцировать, но нужно править БД), обновить объект, обновить ещё один объект). Запросы отправляются к сервису, который реализует REST-API над mongoDB. эти 2 запроса должны быть атомарными.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что штуки вроде uvicorn принципиально не рассчитаны на имение каких-либо разделяемых ресурсов

Comment: @andreymal как решить кейс? Делать распределённый мьютекс или очередь?

Comment: А какая задача решается-то?

Comment: @andreymal добавил описание. Сейчас склоняюсь к связке distributed mutex над редисом

Comment: Никак uvicorn не решает эту проблему. Используйте блокировки на уровне БД.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я склоняюсь к distributed lock

Comment: @hedgehogues тоже вариант, но понадобиться поднимать что-нибудь дополнительное для него.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev редис (=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

threading.Lock работает внутри одного процесса.

multiprocessing.Lock работает в группе процессов если создан в процессе создающем группу.

uvicorn импортирует модуль приложения. Тут есть вариант или сначапла запускает воркеры, а потом импортируе; или сначала импортирует, а потом запускает воркеров. Воркеры запускаются через multiprocessing по умолчанию.

multiprocessing.Lock должен работать, но нужно его правильно подсунуть. В первом случае нужно замонкипатчить стартовый скрипт увикорна чтоб лок был один для всех процессов. Во втором случае лок нужно создать до экземпляра app прямо в коде приложения.

Проверил: переимпортируется модуль  после старта процесса.

В документации и в коде не нашел хуков - нужно патчить.

Comment: Патчить ювикорн выглядит дичью. Ювикорн не делает форк базового процесса с импортом приложения. Я проверил

Comment: Там multiprocessin.spawn сейчас

Comment: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/importer.py#L20 импорт

Comment: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/subprocess.py#L39 форк